# "No tables used" error with phpMyAdmin trigger

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, triggers

I am using a plug in on Wordpress (4.3.1) called Event Manager to create an event calendar. Events are added through pages on Wordpress and the data about each event are stored in a table called "wp_em_events" in the Wordpress MySQL database. On the page where event info is entered I have added a list of cities to select, which are Wordpress categories. These are used to create event calendars for each city. For example, I use this shortcode to create a calendar page for events in Boston: [events_calendar full=1 category="Boston"].

I would like to have the category name included in the table where all of the other event information is stored (wp_em_events), so that I can query this table by city.

I am working on a trigger in phpMyAdmin to get the category name added to the wp_em_events table. It’s a bit of a puzzle to find the category name, but here is how it works:

In the wp_em_event table, each new event has a post_id.

The post_id from the wp_em_event table matches the object_id in the wp_term_relationships table.

The term_taxonomy_id from the wp_term_relationships table matches the term_id in the wp_term_taxonomy table.

The term_id in wp_term_taxonomy matches the term_id in the wp_terms table. The wp_terms also contains the variable “name,” which is the name of the category (e.g., Boston).

In other words:

wp_em_events.post_id = wp_term_relationship.object_id

wp_term_relationship.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id

wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id

So, I created a new field in wp_em_events called “chapter.” If I use this sql code, I can add the category name to chapter:

```
UPDATE wp_em_events
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships on (wp_em_events.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms on (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_terms.term_id) 
SET wp_em_events.chapter = wp_terms.name;
```

I want to set a trigger to insert the wp_terms.name into wp_em_events.chapter every time a new row is inserted into wp_em_events.  I created the trigger with the following code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE DEFINER=`wordpressuser202`@`localhost` TRIGGER `test` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `wp_em_events` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE wp_em_events 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships on (NEW.post_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms on (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_terms.term_id) 
SET NEW.chapter = wp_terms.name; 
END
```

The only difference there is in the UPDATE statement is I changed wp_em_events. to NEW. so post_id and chapter refer to the column of the new row to be inserted.  When I insert a new record, however, I get an error:

## 1096 – No tables used

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: The first problem with your trigger is that it tries to update *all* rows in wp_em_events.  The second problem is that you can't reference the same table with in a trigger, but you're doing it in such an unexpectedly strange way that the error being thrown is apparently not the actual error that's occurring.  Simply `SET NEW.col1 = (SELECT t2.col2 FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON ... WHERE t3.col3 = NEW.col4);` is the way to do what you seem to be trying... not `UPDATE ... SET`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the help. The "for each row" was the default phpMyAdmin added to the syntax. Anyway, here is the new SQL code that works! Thanks again for the assistance.

   `SET NEW.chapter = (SELECT wp_terms.name FROM wp_terms 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_terms.term_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships  ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = NEW.post_id)`

Comment: Glad you solves it but `FOR EACH ROW` was not what I was referring to.  That part means it's a row-based trigger.